# How to transfer file from windows to Unix Machine

Tags: ssh, windows, file-copy, putty

I am working in Windows machine I have connected to Unix Machine using Putty,
I want to transfer file from my local Windows Machine to Connected Unix Machine,
Please suggest what is the command,

Comment: I like putty but I also like cygwin which gives you more than just ssh and sftp functionality.

Answer (score 1):

With `putty` you have a utility called `pscp` (putty secure copy).

In putty create a profile that allow connection without password. Let's name it `mycopy`.

Now copy pscp to local dir. Now you can copy using

```
pscp -profile mycopy *.txt 192.168.1.10:/tmp
```

- `*.txt` local text file
- `192.168.1.10:/tmp` /tmp dir in host with IP 192.168.1.10
- `-profile mycopy` indicate which profile to use

you can fecth a remote file (`/foo/bar/afile.sh`).

```
pscp -profile mycopy 192.168.1.10:/foo/bar/afile.sh .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psftp` connection which is included in Putty installation (PSFTP.EXE at the same folder).

You just enter `sftp <your_machine_ip>` and then use standard ftp commands to copy/paste files between hosts (`put <local_file>` do upload, `get <remote_file>` to download, etc.).